# Subconsulta JOIN, COUNT - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo esta duda, espero me puedan ayudar:
En un sistema de control de horas de trabajadores donde ingresan dichas horas en hojas de tiempo el cual son de periodos de tiempo de una semana, esas horas están asociadas a una o varias tareas y estas mismas están asociadas a uno o varios proyectos. Además registrar una hora en una tarea se puede agregar un nota el cual se puede ver la fecha que se ingreso dicha nota.
El objetivo del query es listar las notas donde haiga mas de una en una misma fecha, el resultado tiene que ser el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora realice este query donde muestra la cantidad de notas por una misma fecha, con la condición que deba haber mas de una nota en una misma fecha:

```
SELECT
        TP.prstart,
        TP.prfinish,
        R.full_name,
        T.task_name,
        COUNT(PR.note) AS cant_note,
        PR.notedate
        FROM 
        prnote PR
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMEENTRY TE ON pr.prrecordid = TE.prid
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMESHEET TS ON TE.prtimesheetid = TS.prid
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMEPERIOD TP ON TP.prid = TS.prtimeperiodid
        LEFT JOIN SRM_RESOURCES R ON TS.prresoruceid = R.id
        LEFT JOIN PRASIGNMENT A ON A.prid = TE.prassignmentid
        LEFT JOIN PRTASK T ON T.prid = A.prtaskid
        LEFT JOIN PROJECTS PRO ON PRO.id = T.prprojectid 
        WHERE PR.prtablename = 'PRtimeEntry' AND PRO.name='USTR'
        GROUP BY
        TP.prstart,
        TP.prfinish,
        R.full_name,
        T.task_name,
        pr.notedate
        HAVING
        COUNT(PR.note) > 1
```

Después de eso quise poner este query como subconsulta del mismo query para poder listar las notas de este mismo, este fue el resultado:

```
SELECT 
X.prstart
X.prfinish,
X.full_name,
X.task_name,
X.note,
X.notedate
FROM(
    SELECT
    TP.prstart,
    TP.prfinish,
    R.full_name,
    T.task_name,
    PR.note,
    PR.notedate
    FROM 
    prnote PR
    LEFT JOIN PRTIMEENTRY TE ON pr.prrecordid = TE.prid
    LEFT JOIN PRTIMESHEET TS ON TE.prtimesheetid = TS.prid
    LEFT JOIN PRTIMEPERIOD TP ON TP.prid = TS.prtimeperiodid
    LEFT JOIN SRM_RESOURCES R ON TS.prresoruceid = R.id
    LEFT JOIN PRASIGNMENT A ON A.prid = TE.prassignmentid
    LEFT JOIN PRTASK T ON T.prid = A.prtaskid
    LEFT JOIN PROJECTS PRO ON PRO.id = T.prprojectid
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
        TP.prstart,
        TP.prfinish,
        R.full_name,
        T.task_name,
        COUNT(PR.note) AS cant_note,
        PR.notedate
        FROM 
        prnote PR
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMEENTRY TE ON pr.prrecordid = TE.prid
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMESHEET TS ON TE.prtimesheetid = TS.prid
        LEFT JOIN PRTIMEPERIOD TP ON TP.prid = TS.prtimeperiodid
        LEFT JOIN SRM_RESOURCES R ON TS.prresoruceid = R.id
        LEFT JOIN PRASIGNMENT A ON A.prid = TE.prassignmentid
        LEFT JOIN PRTASK T ON T.prid = A.prtaskid
        LEFT JOIN PROJECTS PRO ON PRO.id = T.prprojectid 
        WHERE PR.prtablename = 'PRtimeEntry' AND PRO.name='USTR'
        GROUP BY
        TP.prstart,
        TP.prfinish,
        R.full_name,
        T.task_name,
        pr.notedate
        HAVING
        COUNT(PR.note) > 1
    )N --ON N.note = PR.note AND N.note = PR.note --Como igualar el N.note con PR.note para que ----liste las notas de la subconsulta N, ya que en la subconsulta esta como int--
    WHERE PR.prtablename = 'PRtimeEntry' AND PRO.name='USTR'
)X
```

El problema es que después de la subconsulta "N" donde eh puesto el comentario,quiero igualarlo con la nota del query general, pero no se puede porque en la subconsulta esta como count, de que manera puedo igualarlo o hay otra manera para desarrollarlo, les agradecería infinitamente.

Comment: ¿en qué base de datos trabajas? Has añadido etiquetas de 4 motores distintos, deja solamente la del que realmente utilizas, pues eso aumentará tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: ojalá vuelva en junio...

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas hacer una cuenta separada y luego hacer *join* con ese resultado, ya que puedes valerte de la [`función de ventana`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `count()` para contar los registros en cada partición *al vuelo* y luego filtrar el resultado por dicha cuenta, valiéndote de un [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) o de una tabla derivada:

Por ejemplo:

```
with
Datos as (
SELECT   TP.prstart
       , TP.prfinish
       , R.full_name
       , T.task_name
       , PR.note
       , PR.notedate
       , COUNT(1) over (partition by TP.prstart, TP.prfinish, R.full_name, T.task_name, pr.notedate) AS count_notes_in_the_day
  FROM prnote PR
       LEFT JOIN PRTIMEENTRY TE ON pr.prrecordid = TE.prid
       LEFT JOIN PRTIMESHEET TS ON TE.prtimesheetid = TS.prid
       LEFT JOIN PRTIMEPERIOD TP ON TP.prid = TS.prtimeperiodid
       LEFT JOIN SRM_RESOURCES R ON TS.prresoruceid = R.id
       LEFT JOIN PRASIGNMENT A ON A.prid = TE.prassignmentid
       LEFT JOIN PRTASK T ON T.prid = A.prtaskid
       LEFT JOIN PROJECTS PRO ON PRO.id = T.prprojectid 
 WHERE PR.prtablename = 'PRtimeEntry' 
   AND PRO.name='USTR'
)
select   prstart
       , prfinish
       , full_name
       , task_name
       , note
       , notedate
  from Datos
 where count_notes_in_the_day > 1
```